# Open camera inside fragment

Tags: android, camera, fragment, android-camera

Is it possible to use camera in `fragment` like view, so that it wouldn't open another **app** and go away from my special app?

I want something like `SurfaceView` with camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, Check this [link](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment) .

Basically overwritting the `SurfaceView` and integrating the `camera picture callback`.

example code :

```
/* Surface on which the camera projects it's capture results.
*/
class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here

            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

with a camera picture callback like:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image retrieval failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Flawed... Missing arguments for default constructor and implementation of the View programmatically, since doing it via XML calls a bland constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Native implementation is way better.

> XML

```
<com.google.android.cameraview.CameraView
android:id="@+id/camera"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
app:autoFocus="true"
app:aspectRatio="4:3"
app:facing="back"
app:flash="auto"/>
```

> Inside Activity/Fragment

**Start camera**

```
  mCameraView.start();
```

**Stop camera**

```
  mCameraView.stop();
```

**[Open source: Google](https://opensource.google.com/projects/cameraview)**

Requires API Level 9. The library uses Camera 1 API on API Level 9-20 and Camera2 on 21 and above.

Comment: this is awesome