# Camera preview in fragment surfaceview

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, camera, surfaceview

Recently I am trying to make android app in Xamarin that will use a camera preview to recognize people and measure the distance between a photographer and the target.

To achieve this I need a simple camera preview that doesn't have to capture any pictures or so, just plain preview.

I was able to open a camera and preview it as a full screen but it is not what I need. My code doesn't report any bugs, application deploys and launches properly, yet the surfaceView in my Fragment is black.
Logcat throws a message from Camera that app passed null surface.

My MainActivity.cs:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        bool color = false;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.cs - it is the fragment with surfaceView (second fragment contains only one simple textview, not relevant to the case):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Hardware;
using Java.Lang;

namespace App1
{
    public class FirstFragment : Fragment, ISurfaceHolderCallback
    {
    static Camera camera = null;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    private string tag = "FirstFragment";

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        start_camera();
        // Create your fragment here
    }

    private void start_camera()
    {
        try
        {
            camera = Camera.Open();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e)
        {
            Log.Error(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.GetParameters();
        //modify parameter
        param.PreviewFrameRate = 20;
        param.SetPreviewSize(176, 144);
        camera.SetParameters(param);
        try
        {
            //camera.SetPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            //camera.StartPreview();
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
    }

    public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder arg0, Android.Graphics.Format arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {

        Log.Error(tag, "surfaceDestroyed() is called");
            // Stop preview and release camera 
            if (holder.Surface != null)
        {
            camera.StopPreview();
            //mCamera.release();  //should we release camera here?
            //mCamera = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Error(tag, "surfaceDestroyed(): preview surface does not exist");
        }
    }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FirstFragment, container, false);
            surfaceView = view.FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surfaceView1);
            surfaceHolder = surfaceView.Holder;
            surfaceHolder.AddCallback(this);
            camera.SetPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.StartPreview();
            surfaceHolder.SetType(SurfaceType.PushBuffers);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

And here are layouts:

Main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <fragment
        android:name="App1.FirstFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="279.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment1" />
    <fragment
        android:name="App1.SecondFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And FirstFragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am aware of that the reason may be simple, but i made a lot of reasearch how to fix it with no success yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205352/open-camera-inside-fragment

Comment: I have seen this topic already, but my problem is rather about translating the code from Java to C#, I might be wrong though.